# Refresh drop down cell value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I have a drop down cell which has a list of values.

[image]

The problem is, I want to refresh the cell value to the 1st value of the list "JR" or other, whenever the I change the value on the "S235" cell.

Is this possible?

I've looked for guides on this, but all they do is updating the drop down list values, and not refreshing the cell value.

Comment: The only way to achieve it is to use macros, there is no other way in Excel to change content of cells entered by a user.

Comment: Are "JR", "J0" and "J2" named ranges?